# How to convert a parametrised vector function in terms of arc length to a vector function in terms of t

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Given a vector function $\overrightarrow r(t)$, we know that its arc length $s$ between time $t=a$ to $t=b$ is given by the integral $s = \int_a^b \sqrt{\overrightarrow r'(t)} dt $. We can reparametrise this in terms of $s$ by writing $s = f(t)$ and rearranging to obtain $t$ in terms of $s$ by writing $t = g(s)$. We then plug in this new value of $t$ as a function of $s$ into the original vector to obtain $\overrightarrow r(t(s))$. This new vector function in terms of $s$ allows us to find at what point the curve is at after travelling a distance $s$ along it.

My question is how can we convert $\overrightarrow r(t(s))$ back to $\overrightarrow r(t)$? I know that $s = \int_a^b \sqrt{\overrightarrow r'(t)} dt $ so I would guess that to obtain $t$ in terms of $s$ again I would have to divide both sides by $dt$, but there is still the issue of the limits of the definite integral. And this still does not allow me to find $t$. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you only have $\vec{r}(t(s))$ you cannot get $\vec{r}(t)$ because there are many, effectively infinite, parametrizations that lead to $\vec{r}(t(s))$

Comment: @enzotib I can understand why that's the case but even so, I would like to find even one of those infinite parametrisations. Basically given $\overrightarrow r(t(s))$ I want to be able to find $\overrightarrow r(t)$.